# decimal to binary in java

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I'm having trouble in getting the binary. I do not know what's wrong. The binary number always ends up in gibberish. Also some parts like the `new int[31]` thing was from HW but I can't get around to make print the actual binary.

```
public class DectoBinary {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a nonnegative integer: ");
        int value = CONSOLE.nextInt();
        while (value < 0) {
            System.out.print("number outside range.");
            System.out.print
                ("Please enter a nonnegative interger more than 0: ");
            value = CONSOLE.nextInt();
        }
        int[] intArray = new int[31];
        decimalToBinary(value, intArray);
        System.out.println(value + "" + intArray);
    }
    public static int[] decimalToBinary(int value, int[]intArray) {
        int i = 0;
        while (value != 0) {
            if (value % 2 == 1)
                intArray[i] = 1;

            else
                intArray[i] = 0;

            value /= 2;
            i++;
        }
        return intArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: What inputs have you tried and what output did you get?

Comment: what version of java are you using? Is it mandatory to implement the method yourself? this is because java 7 has what you want out of the box.

Comment: I've tried small numbers like 10 and 100 as the inputs but the intArray ususally becomes like [I@1ced821

Comment: @JuanAlbertoLópezCavallotti Im using a program DrJava and yes it is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is on this line:

```
System.out.println(value + "" + intArray);
```

You cannot print an array of integers like this: you should either convert it to string, or write a loop that prints the array digit by digit:

```
for (int i : inrArray) {
    System.out.print(intArray[i]);
}
System.out.println();
```

You do not need to pass in the output array as well: you can create it inside the function.

```
public static int[] decimalToBinary(int value) {
    int count = 1;
    int tmp = value;
    while (tmp != 0) {
        tmp /= 2;
        count++;
    }
    int[] intArray = new int[count];
    // Do the conversion here...
    return intArray;
}
```

Comment: Ive tried it but the output prints a lot of zeros for numbers like 10 & 100

Comment: @user1239224 Since your method returns an array of 31 ints regardless of the value passed in, all leading zeros are included into the output. You could change the program and return a smaller array that excludes leading zeros.

Comment: wait but how can I include the i if I'm printing it in the main method? I thought I was only return the intArray?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight there is a second problem (assuming he wants the number to be right aligned) he's adding the numbers in the opposite order so the number is backwards.

Comment: @user1239224 That's OK, you can return a *smaller* int array. By the way, you do not need to pass it in: moving `int[] intArray = new int[31]` inside `decimalToBinary` would be perfectly acceptable. Moreover, you do not need to make it `new int[31]`: you could copy `value` to a temporary variable, count the number of times you need to divide by two to get it to zero, and use the count to create `int[] intArray = new int[count]`.

Comment: dang if that's true can you send me a link so I can continue to work on the problem?

Comment: @user1239224 Take a look at the edit. Of course you'll need to rewrite the call to `int[] intArray = decimalToBinary(value);`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [Integer.toBinaryString(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the is a very simple way to get binary numbers in java using BigInteger

```
public String dectoBin(int num){
    String s = ""+num;
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s);
    String bin = bi.toString(2);
    return bin
}
```

`BigInteger.toString(2)` returns the number stored on the numerical base specified inside the parenthesis. Is a very easy way to get arround this problems.

Comment: It's a homework assignment I doubt he can use functions like that to do it for him.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(value + "" + intArray); 
the 'intArray' is a arrays's address, so, if you want to get actual binary you can use Arrays.toString(intArray)

Answer (score 0):

As dasblinkenlight you need to print the array item by item. If you want a nice alternative, you can use a recursive printing of value mod 2 (modulo 2 gives you 1 or 0)

```
/** print directly*/
public static void decimalToBinary(int value) {

    if(value > 1){
         System.out.print(decimalToBinary(value/2) + "" + (value%2)); 
        /**recursion with implicit cast to string*/
    } else {
        System.out.print( (value==0)?"":"1");
   }
}
```

It works with any Base

Answer (score 0):

Well actually to print the array, because all the slots in the array are initialized at 0 you need to detect where the first one begins, so.
you need to replace

```
System.out.println(value + "" + intArray);
```

with something like this;

```
System.out.println(vale + " ");
boolean sw = false;
for(int i=0;i<intArray.length;i++){
    if(!sw)
        sw = (intArray[i]==1);//This will detect when the first 1 appears
    if(sw)
        System.out.println(intArray[1]); //This will print when the sw changes to true everything that comes after
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program to convert Decimal nos. into Binary.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class decimalToBinary {

    static int howManyTerms (int n) {
        int term = 0;

        while (n != 0) {
            term ++;
            n /= 2;
        }

        return term;
    }

    static String revArrayofBin2Str (int[] Array) {
        String ret = "";
        for (int i = Array.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            ret += Integer.toString(Array[i]);

        return ret;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print ("Enter any no.: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int[] bin = new int[howManyTerms (num)];

        int dup = num, el = -1;

        while (dup != 0) {
            int rem = dup % 2;
            bin [++el] = rem;
            dup /= 2;
        }

        String d2b = revArrayofBin2Str(bin);

        System.out.println("Binary of " + num + " is: " + d2b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simple java code for decimal to binary using only primitive type int, hopefully it should help beginners.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DtoB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try { // for Exception handling of taking input from user.

            System.out.println("Please enter a number");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String input = br.readLine();       
            int x = Integer.parseInt(input);

            int bin = 0;
            int p = 1;
            while (x > 0) {
                int r = x % 2;
                bin = (r * p) + bin;
                x = x / 2;
                p *= 10;
            }
            System.out.println("Binary of " + input + " is = " + bin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid decimal number.");
            System.exit(1);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```